# The progress-bar gif keeps in appending

Tags: bug, status-declined, ajax

Normally, I browse on a very high-speed network which sometimes goes crazy and dies out. This is rare case, but happens.

It happened around 10 minutes ago and I noticed this:

[image: Progress bar]

All the single **dots** visible are from [image: this] at same moment.

I'd request that instead of appending the loader-gif on every click, just do it once on first click and set the click listener off.

[image: Image 2]
<sub>Had to submit this image :P</sub>

**P.S.**: Don't know if any other tag is applicable here.

Comment: Related: [Subsequent clicks on close appends extra loading animations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55208) and [Multiple spinners when saving comment edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55211)

Comment: Did you consider *not* clicking several times while the first spinner is displayed? Pushing several additional requests to the server on a slow connection won't help matters I'm afraid.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You're no fun :/

Comment: @hjpotter92, I suppose you're right. Must be Friday :)

Comment: Have to agree with @FrédéricHamidi here... Entirely avoidable by... not clicking so many times ;)

Comment: @Oded in such case guess that my own bug (see above) is also [meta-tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Well... yes.